# fadeOut current element on click of cancel button

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is my code where I am creating dynamic element on click of ADD button.
And i want to fadeOut element onclick of buttton only not on click of div

here is my code

```html
<head>
 <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#btn").click(function(){
    $("#new").append("<div>New li <button>X</button></div>");
   })
   
   $("#new").on('click','div',function(){
    $(this).fadeOut();
   })
  })
  
 </script>

 <input type="button" name="btn" id="btn" value="ADD">
<div id="new">
</ul>
```

this just fadeout on click of div and I don't want this behaviour

Comment: change the second parameter 'div' to whatever is your cancel button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#btn").click(function(){
            $("#new").append("<div class='ParentDiv'>New li <button>X</button></div>");
        });       
        $("#new").on('click','button',function(){
            $(this).closest(".ParentDiv").fadeOut();
        });
    });      
</script>

<input type="button" name="btn" id="btn" value="ADD">
<div id="new">
</div>
```